# WhereGreaterThan returns no results in LuceneQuery (RavenDB)

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm having an issue querying for values that are greater than a certain value with lucene.  My data is dynamic, so Linq is not an option.

The problem, in short, is when I query with WhereGreaterThan I get zero results even though my Asset.Data has a price greater than a value.  This applies to WhereGreaterThanOrEquals, WhereLessThan, and WhereLessThanOrEquals as well.

```
public class AssetDataSearch : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Asset>
{
    public AssetDataSearch()
    {
        Map = (docs) => 
            from d in docs
            select new
            {
                DataType = d.DataType,
                _ = d.SearchableParameters.Select(s => CreateField(s.Key, s.Value))
            };
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var assets = new []
        {
            new Asset()
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Data = new ListingData()
                {
                    Beds = 5,
                    Baths = 5,
                    ListingType = ListingTypeEnum.Condo,
                    Price = 100
                }
            },
            new Asset()
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Data = new ListingData()
                {
                    LotSize = 55,
                    SqFeet = 89,
                    YearBuilt = 1965,
                    Price = 200
                }
            },
        };
        RavenHelper.InitTestingStore();
        using (var session = RavenDB.RavenUtility.OpenSession())
        {
            foreach(var a in assets)
                session.Store(a);
            session.SaveChanges();
            var assetsInDb = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Asset>().WaitForNonStaleResults().ToArray();
            var n = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Asset, AssetDataSearch>().WhereEquals("Price", 100).ToArray(); // returns expected results
            var gt = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Asset, AssetDataSearch>().WhereGreaterThan("Price", 60).ToArray(); // returns nothing
            var lt = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Asset, AssetDataSearch>().WhereLessThan("Price", 60).ToArray();  // returns nothing
        }
     }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that RavenDB interprets the price values as strings, not numbers. Take a look [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/appendixes/lucene-indexes-usage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the Raven Google group.  It turns out I have to query with the same data type as the data.  So, in this case since "Price" is a decimal, I have to pass in 60M to the where clause:

```
var gt = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Asset, AssetDataSearch>().WhereGreaterThan("Price", 60M).ToArray();
```